# populating form field conditionally

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In an MS Access 2010 database, I have a form called `CommunicationForm` which is based on `CommunicationTable`.  The database contains two tables, `Clients` and `CommunicationTable`. Two of the text boxes on `CommunicationForm` need to be populated as follows:

```
If IsNull(CommunicationTable.LastName):  
    CommunicationForm.FirstName = Clients.FirstName 
    CommunicationForm.LastName = Clients.LastName  
Else:  
    CommunicationForm.FirstName = CommunicationTable.FirstName 
    CommunicationForm.LastName = CommunicationTable.LastName
```

How can I accomplish this?

I uploaded a simplified version of the database containing just enough to recreate the problem at [this file sharing site](http://jmp.sh/v/7UA32Xw7iUtQ2lDY1ouA).

If anyone needs to know, the rationale for this odd requirement is that this is a transitional period between an old non-normalized data structure and a new normalized data structure.  Eventually, we will get rid of the name fields in CommunicationTable.  But for the timebeing, how and where do I use vba to accomplish the requirement above?

Comment: CommunicationForm will modify data in CommunicationTable, Clients or readonly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query qryClients with SQL string with INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT IIF(ISNULL(CommunicationTable.LastName), Clients.LastName, 
  CommunicationTable.LastName) AS LastName,
  IIF(ISNULL(CommunicationTable.FirstName), Clients.FirstName, 
  CommunicationTable.FirstName) AS FirstName
FROM CommunicationTable
INNER JOIN Clients
ON CommunicationTable.ClientID = Clients.ClientID;
```

Then

```
CommunicationForm.RecordSource = "qryClients"
CommunicationForm.LastName.ControlSource = "LastName"
CommunicationForm.FirstName.ControlSource = "FirstName"
```

Comment: Thank you. +1 for pointing in a promising direction.  However, each client has many communications. The user selects a specific communication from a continuous form, and the CommunicationID from the selected communication form is what is used to retrieve the data for a specific form. Also, there are many other fields in the communication form besides FirstName and LastName.  I left date and communication fields in the version at the file sharing site to represent this.  How does all this change your recommendation?

Comment: At this point in the code, NO. The name is just for printing purposes.